# How do I prove whether this formula is valid or satisfiable? $\exists xy[P(x,y) \rightarrow \forall xy\ P(x,y)]$

Tags: logic

By **valid/satisfiable** I mean in the context of propositional logic. The following formula is:

$$\exists xy[P(x,y) \rightarrow \forall xy\ P(x,y)]$$

I understand that P is considered to be a predicate symbol, by P(x,y) is a formula that should evaluate to true or false. However, how do I go about solving this kind of problems if I don't have information on what x and y are?

Comment: This is called the drinkers paradox.  Either $\exists xy .Pxy$ or $\lnot \exists xy .Pxy$

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Is the proof meant to be in natural language form or is there a mathematical proof for this?

Comment: That is for you to decide.

Comment: If I were asked whether a given first-order sentence is valid and whether it is satisfiable, I might start by considering a particular structure and checking whether the sentence is true in that structure. Being lazy, I'd choose the structure to be very simple, perhaps just one element. If the formula is true in that one structure, I at least know it's satisfiable. If the formula is false in that structure, I at least know it isn't valid. So one of the two questions, "valid?" or "satisfiable?" is immediately answered.

Comment: To answer the other question, I'd need to check whether some other structure gives the opposite truth value for the given sentence. That can be hard work, but in the present case it's not too bad.Think about what would have to happen in a structure to produce the opposite truth value, and try to design a structure like that. If you can't design one, look for the reason why you can't, i.e., a proof that there's no such structure.

Comment: Your sentence can be rewritten in the equivalent but perhaps slightly clearer form $$\exists xy\forall uv[p(x,y)\to P(u,v).$$ Intuitively, that says that $P(x,y)$ attains a minimum truth value. It's analogous to $$\forall xy\exists uv[f(x,y)\le f(u,v)$$ which says that $f(x,y)$ has an absolute minimum, and is true if $f$ is a function whose range is a finite set of real numbers.

Answer (score -2):

By the rules I learned the sentence is not well formed, so it is neither valid nor satisfiable.  The square brackets mean the existential quantifier applies to everything inside, so you can't requantify over them with the universal quantifier.  It would be legal to write $\exists xy P(x,y) \implies \forall xy P(x,y)$ but this still creates an opportunity for confusion because of the reuse of $x,y$.  I find it better to write 
$$\exists xy P(x,y) \implies \forall wz P(w,z)$$
where the scope of the quantifiers is obvious.  I have seen authors who specifically allow reuse of variables, but they have to be very careful about the rules for substitution.  Some comments have said the rules they are used to accept your sentence, but it is equivalent to the one I set in display mode.

This makes it easier to see that the sentence is satisfiable but not valid.  If $\forall wz P(w,z)$ is true the implication is true as well.  If $P(x,y)$ is true sometimes and false sometimes the implication is false.  We could easily construct a model for each of the previous sentences to prove our claim.

Comment: I slightly disagree with you there. The square bracket means: the quantifier applies to every FREE variable inside the bracket. That is, the scope of a quantifier preceding a parenthesis or a bracket does not range over variables bound by other quantifiers. You might want to change that. I hope that was useful, cheers!

Comment: @BertrandWittgenstein'sGhost:  that depends on the syntax rules you are working with.  The first set I worked with forced a set of parentheses just after the quantifier to show the range of the quantifier.  This would demand $\exists xy (P(x,y)) \implies \forall wz( P(w,z))$.  It seems a little clumsy, but there is good sense in it.

Comment: I agree with @BertrandWittgenstein'sGhost -- I happened to cover this exact material in class today, and the professor allowed nested quantifiers with the innermost quantifier having precedence (equivalently, the outer quantifier only applies to free variables).

Comment: @RossMillikan I agree with your correction, but notice: $\forall x,y,z[\exists x_1[P(x_1,y) \rightarrow P(x,z,x_1) ]]$ in this case if we separate each atomic formula into one which has its own independent quantifier, then it would not hold the same meaning.

Comment: $$\exists xy[P(x,y)\to\forall xy P(x,y)]$$ has the same meaning as $$\exists xy[P(x,y)\to\forall uv P(u,v)]$$ or $$\exists xy\forall uv[P(x,y)\to P(u,v)].$$